# How to investigate occasional water-pressure problems?

Tags: water-pressure

After living in the house for about 10 years, a few weeks ago we started noticing *occasional* drops of water-pressure in the showers and faucets.

It is not consistent -- after one person struggled with a shower, the next to use it would be happy. The house has four bathrooms and multiple showers are in contemporaneous use some times, but that was always the case. Besides, some of the pressure-drops would occur even when no other shower were in use...

When this happens, it seems to affect the whole house -- even the stream refilling a toilet-tank is match-thin.

Suspecting external factors, we asked the neighbors, but they say, they don't experience any such problem.

The plumbing is "new" -- same 10 years old -- and the pipes are all 3/4". There is a house-wide water-softener in the basement.

I could understand some piece of debris getting into a pipe -- or the water-softener deteriorating -- but that would make the problem constant. Yet, it strikes only occasionally.

The water-heater and -boiler -- the same device -- is also 10 years-old. Mid-summer I had to replace a leaking backup valve under one of the kitchen sinks, which required shutting off the hot water pipe at the heater. But that was months ago and I turned all the valves back.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a well and pump, or does your water come from a utility/municipal entity already pressurized?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, it comes from the city. I'm alluding to that, when I mention asking the neighbors -- who have no problems despite being served by the same main.